# Hive Query is not returning any value

Tags: sql, hive

I'm sure this is a syntax error in my query.  What am I doing wrong?

```
describe codes_to_jobs;                            
1037.586: [GC 487958K->420946K(4185792K), 0.0115291 secs]
OK
job_id  string  
text    string  
....

select job_id from codes_to_jobs limit 5;            
820.769: [GC 358434K->293732K(4185792K), 0.0122444 secs]
OK
'8144439'
'8173679'
'8223174'
'8388313'
'8420908'
```

`select * from codes_to_jobs where job_id = '8144439';`

No results.

Thanks!

Comment: you can get by using like operator like '%8144439%'

Comment: use ='\'8144439\'' if quotes are there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting output because you have '' in your data.

one solution is to match the pattern

```
select * from codes_to_jobs where job_id like '%8144439%'
```

second solution is to escape single quotes.

```
select * from codes_to_jobs where job_id = '\'8144439\''
```

Comment: Thanks!  So I assume I don't need the quotes in my .hql script?